# Probability - Random Variable Transformation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I can't figure out what I'm supposed to do in this exercise:

For the following case, identify the distribution of $Y = aX$, $a > 0$.

$X ∼ \text{Exp}(λ)$, $λ > $0

$$ f_x(x) = λe^{-\lambda x}, x \geq 0. $$

What I'm trying to do:

$$f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \left| \frac{d}{dy} g^{-1}(y) \right| $$

Where $g(x) = aX$.

$$ f_Y(y) = \lambda e^{-\lambda \frac{y}{a}} \left| \frac{d}{dy} \frac{y}{a} \right| = \frac{d}{dy} \frac{y}{a} = \frac{1}{a}$$

Where i found:

$$f_Y(y) = \frac{\lambda}{a} e^{-\lambda \frac{y}{a}}, y \geq 0$$

Does that make sense and answer the question? Or do I need something more?

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: something like that $$f_Y(y) = f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \left| \frac{d}{dy} g^{-1}(y) \right|$$ where g(x) = aX, but i'dont know if what i'm doing it's correct

Comment: Please edit your post to include your attempts. What you're doing looks correct. Have you found $g^{-1}$?

Comment: BTW, there's no need for the absolute values

Comment: The question asks you to identify the distribution. You've found the pdf. What is it the pdf of? Hint: you've already seen it in this question

Comment: It's an exponential with $\frac{\lambda}{a}$ ?

Comment: Yes. $$
\mathbb P\{Y\le y\}=\mathbb P\{X\le \frac ya\}=1-e^{-\lambda\frac ya}\,.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm still learning this part about variable transformations! But thank you so much for your time.

Comment: CDFs are often easier to deal with than PDFs. This is a prime example.